# how to save .doc file from url in python?

Tags: python, download, save

I'm trying to figure out how to download/save a .doc file from the internet to somewhere on my computer.

I'm familiar with the urllib2 module and .read(), but I haven't figured out how to save a formatted .doc file to a location on my computer. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library, this is how you do it:

```
r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
if r.status_code == 200:
    with open('document.doc', 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r.iter_content():
            f.write(chunk)
    f.close()
```